# How to solve electron and grpc version problem in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, electron

I have a angular project trying to run in windows application. Project includes firebase, electron. I am trying to build and publish windows desktop app but it failed with many errors

**package.json**

```
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.2",
"@angular/common": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/material": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.4",
 "firebase": "^6.4.0",
*dev dependencies*
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
"@angular/language-service": "^7.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^11.9.3",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"electron": "^6.0.10",
"electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~8.0.2",
"tslint": "~5.12.1",
"typescript": "~3.2.4"
```

For electron build and publish I used

```
electron-builder build --win --publish never
```

I got the below log when i executed above command

```
electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=10.0.18362
description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\User\example\package.json
author is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\User\example\package.json
rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=grpc@1.23.3 platform=win32 arch=x64



⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
                out=
> grpc@1.23.3 install C:\User\example\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Sandeep.Lagishetty\Desktop\TextusUI\desktop-app-demo\beetextui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Sandeep.Lagishetty\Desktop\TextusUI\desktop-app-demo\beetextui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v6.1' (1)

                errorOut=node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.23.3 and electron@6.1.4 (electron-v6.1 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2013
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Sandeep.Lagishetty\\Desktop\\TextusUI\\desktop-app-demo\\beetextui\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Sandeep.Lagishetty\\Desktop\\TextusUI\\desktop-app-demo\\beetextui\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=electron-v6.1"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Sandeep.Lagishetty\Desktop\TextusUI\desktop-app-demo\beetextui\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Sandeep.Lagishetty\Desktop\TextusUI\desktop-app-demo\beetextui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\User\example\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.1-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v6.1' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\User\example\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\User\example\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install""--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\User\examplebeetextui\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.23.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.23.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-08T08_21_02_233Z-debug.log

                command='C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' rebuild grpc@1.23.3
                workingDir=
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ExampleApp package: `electron-builder build --win --publish never`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ExampleApp package script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-08T08_21_02_483Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Error states that you need `windows-build-tools`.

Error logs directs you to [node-gyp repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows), from where you can find directives on how to install. Try again after installing the `windows-build-tools`.